# Nameservers on CPanel/WHM, with No IP?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nameserver

I added two nameserver with the same IP on initial setup and now in **Main >> DNS Functions >> Nameservers IPs** I see my Nameservers with No IPs

How Can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why this happens, because cPanel can't resolve nameservers it display "No IPs" even if it's setup correctly.

Some times this issue can be fixed by editing `/etc/nameserverips`